# How to fetch images from Imgur API in Java

Tags: java, android, api, imgur, mobile-development

Hello I'm new in Java Android development and i was following a tutorial on how to fetch data from Imgur API.
After I finished the tutorial i tired the app but i don't see any images or data on the emulator bc i think that i did some mistake in my code.
If anyone can give me a sample how to implement the code or example.
Thank you in advance

Tutorial -> https://progur.com/2016/11/create-imgur-client-android.html

My Code -> https://www.codepile.net/pile/A6bkN9eW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running your code exactly the same way except the url in your `request` object and I was able to fetch the images from Imgur API. I used the url given in the tutorial as below:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
           .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/user/rising/0.json")
            .header("Authorization","Client-ID 4ec810250ea92fb")
            .header("User-Agent","Epicture")
            .build();
```

You might have used the wrong API. Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed the API url but still i have just a white screen in my emulator. I don't retrieve the images. Can you send me all your code ?

Comment: Go to this link https://github.com/ArunGohil/Epicture for reference. Have a look in your onResponse method.